# 32-bit ADD on Aarch64 assembly

Tags: arm64

This is my first post here and I'm also kind of new to arm64 assembly, so I'm trying to do some arithmetic, but for example when I try to do an addition it seems to do it in 32-bit.
Here's my code:

```
.data
msg:    .asciz  "Value 1: "
msg2:   .asciz  "Value 2: "
result: .asciz  "Result: %d\n"
fmt:    .asciz  "%d"
.balign 8
value1: .quad   0
.balign 8
value2: .quad   0
.balign 16
lr_value: .quad      0

.text
.global main
main:   
        adr x0, lr_value           
        str x30, [x0]     

        //Display message
        adr x0,msg
        bl printf
        //Input first value
        adr x0,fmt
        adr x1,value1
        bl scanf

        //Display second message
        adr x0,msg2
        bl printf
        //Input second value 
        adr x0,fmt
        adr x1,value2
        bl scanf

        //Load first and second value
        adr x1,value1
        ldr x1,[x1]
        adr x2,value2
        ldr x2,[x2]
        //Add both values on x1
        add x1,x1,x2
        //Show result
        adr x0,result
        bl printf

        adr x0,lr_value
        ldr x30,[x0]
        mov w0,#0
        ret
```

And here's the output:

```
Value 1: 2147483647
Value 2: 1
Result: -2147483648
```

What am I doing wrong? I've also tried multiplication and substraction

**Edit:** Solved it, turns out I had to use %ld instead of %d, thank you Nate Eldredge!

Comment: Probably you want `%ld` in your format string...

Comment: Oh, it works! thank you so much I've having problems with that. Thanks again!